# If statement within Case

Tags: c++, vector, switch-statement

The following code generates different characters based on choices taken by the user previously using a bool function. The user can choose whether or not to have some of the characters, such as "numbers" or "Uppercase characters".

The issue I'm having is that after I've implemented a *switch/case* system to *fully* randomize which character goes first, the choices aren't respected anymore.

Per example, the user can choose numbers off, yet sometimes numbers will still show up in the sequence. This does *not* occur with the switch taken off for randomization purposes (which keeps the sequence to *Lowercase*+*Uppercase*+*Symbols*+*Numbers*).

Should I be using if/else here, or is something else most likely wrong with the rest of the code?

```
int randomCharacter_cases;
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    // If no appropriate option was selected, then the user will go back to selection:
    if(StrongPass==0 && lowercase==0 && Uppercase==0 && numbers==0 && symbols==0)
    {
        // CODE
    }


    // This selects the order of each character:
    randomCharacter_cases=rand()%4+1;

    switch(randomCharacter_cases)
    {
    // Lowercase characters;
    case 1:
    {
        if(StrongPass==1 || lowercase==1)
        {
            keeper.push_back((char)(rand()%(122-97+1)+97));
        }
        break;
    }
    // Uppercase characters;
    case 2:
    {
        if(StrongPass==1 || Uppercase==1)
        {
            keeper.push_back((char)(rand()%(90-65+1)+65));
        }
        break;
    }
    // Symbols;
    case 3:
    {
        if(StrongPass==1 || symbols==1)
        {
            keeper.push_back((char)(rand()%(64-33+1)+33));
        }
        break;
    }
    // Numbers;
    case 4:
    {
        if(StrongPass==1 || numbers==1)
        {
            keeper.push_back((char)(rand()%(57-48+1)+48));
        }
        break;
    }

    }

}
```

EDIT: StrongPass, in this particular piece of code, is done in the case where the user doesn't wish to choose what characters he doesn't generate (for example, you may choose any of the four char. types, or you may simply say that you want an automatically generated password, which uses all four types of characters).

**This** is the function used to determine each individual usage:

```
bool yesno()
{
string inp;
cin>>inp;
if(!(inp=="Y" || inp=="y" || inp=="N" || inp=="n"))
{
    cout<<"Y or N:";
    yesno();
}
if(inp=="Y" || inp=="y")
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Usage example:

```
// Choices we take for each password option:
bool StrongPass,lowercase,Uppercase,symbols,numbers;

// Function for generating random numbers:
srand (time(NULL));

// Default strong options, for easy use:
cout<<"Would you like an automatic S.T.R.O.N.G. password?: ";
StrongPass=yesno();

// If you'd like a more advanced password:
if(StrongPass==0)
{
    cout<<"Length of the password?: ";
    cin>>length;
    cout<<"Length of the password?: "<<length<<"\n";
    cout<<"Include lowercase characters?: ";
    lowercase=yesno();
    cout<<"Include uppercase characters?: ";
    Uppercase=yesno();
    cout<<"Include symbols?: ";
    symbols=yesno();
    cout<<"Include numbers?: ";
    numbers=yesno();
}

// The password itself is generated here:
int randomCharacter_cases;
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    // This selects the order of each character:
    randomCharacter_cases=rand()%4+1;

    switch(randomCharacter_cases)
    {
    // Lowercase characters;
    case 1:
    {
        if(StrongPass==1 || lowercase==1)
        {
            keeper.push_back((char)(rand()%(122-97+1)+97));
        }
        break;
    }
    // Uppercase characters;
    case 2:
    {
        if(StrongPass==1 || Uppercase==1)
        {
            keeper.push_back((char)(rand()%(90-65+1)+65));
        }
        break;
    }
    // Symbols;
    case 3:
    {
        if(StrongPass==1 || symbols==1)
        {
            keeper.push_back((char)(rand()%(64-33+1)+33));
        }
        break;
    }
    // Numbers;
    case 4:
    {
        if(StrongPass==1 || numbers==1)
        {
            keeper.push_back((char)(rand()%(57-48+1)+48));
        }
        break;
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: The magic numbers are strong with this one.  I notice that something always happens if StrongPass == 1.  To help everyone, you should include a driver and expected input and output.  Right now, our ability to help is limited.

Comment: I strongly recommend replacing every magic number with a constant such as `'a'` or `'z' - 'a'`, so that people can read and understand the code more easily. It is also going to be __much__ easier to test this if, instead of inserting random stuff, you just repeatedly call each of the four "character generator" expressions repeatedly and look at their output. As it is, you have no way of knowing which one might be wrong.

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelDorgan. The fact is, the code is *very* long and ultimately complicated. AFAIK, I shouldn't be posting the whole thing - I'll simply be making an edit to explain what each "magic number" refers to.

Comment: They are ASCII ranges - we get that.  It is just harder to read than it otherwise should be.

Comment: Better: make a random_range helper function, which accepts the first and last possible character as inputs, and does all the `rand()%(last-first+1)+first` stuff in exactly one place.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your code on the `case 4` condition.  Examine your variables, then you may be able to determine why you hit this case unexpectedly.  You may be experiencing a memory corruption not being shown here.

Comment: @J. Doe Instead of these magic numbers like 97, 65, etc.  Just define 4 static arrays "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "0123456789", and another string that has the symbols.  Then take a random character from these arrays.  You are then not tied to ASCII, and you eliminate the usage of magic numbers.

Comment: Also, for a password generation function, keep in mind you may want to control your random seed more directly.

Comment: Your new `yesno` function is recursive?

Comment: It doesn't call itself in any circumstance @MichaelDorgan

Comment: `yesno` doesn't work as you expect. Calling `yesno` inside `yesno` doesn't `goto` the start of the function. It adds another call to the function to the stack with it's own state.

Comment: lol - read your code.  `yesno()` calls `yesno()` in the input if statement.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, @MichaelDorgan - thought you were referring to the return statements. I'm a bit in a pickle here - how could that affect how the function messes up?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really understanding. Could you please explain? @FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: A few ways, but I also don't see how `yesno()` has anything to with your state machine in the first code example.  They don't call each other.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan adding an example of usage right now, editing.

Comment: @Killzone_Kid got it for you.  Your `yesno()` issue will bite you later, but isn't the cause of numbers appearing in your data.

Comment: @J.Doe When you call `yesno` again you create another call to the function. It has it's own instance of `inp` that is unrelated to the first call's instance. Changing *that* `inp` won't do anything and the original value given by the user will remain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Per example, the user can choose numbers off, yet sometimes numbers will still show up in the sequence.

Your symbols random generation includes numbers (48...57), so even if you switch numbers off symbols may produce numbers

Comment: This is the correct answer. Not sure how I missed this.

Comment: Hey! Thank you! @MichaelDorgan

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, **"*Should I be using if/else here*"** - Sure. It is perfectly acceptable to use a `if/else` statement within a `switch` `case` statement.

Comment: I was implying whether or not I should use *if/else* instead of *switch/case* - but that doesn't solve the issue that the switch/case has been giving me.

Comment: Matter of opinion. My own coding guidelines say never embed another control structure in a switch. This comes of working with lots of Windows C code which were basically one huge switch.

Comment: Agreed! I'm just curious and asking on why this, particularly, isn't working @NeilButterworth

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting numbers is because either `StrongPass` or `numbers` is equal to one. Since you haven't provided where/how/ you are assigning values to this, the best advice we can give you is as follows:

If you don't want numbers to appear, ensure that both `StrongPass` AND `numbers` is equal to 0.

[EDIT]
You're input selection function is broken. You have a recursive call that you are no longer catching the value of. Not sure how you are USING this function, though.

If the first call fails (user doesn't select valid input), the recursive call's return value IS NOT CAUGHT. The original function returns 0 no matter what. Even if the recursive call was a "successful" input.

Comment: Not necessarily - what if his input array had garbage or previous data?  What about an array overwrite.  We cannot definitively say anything except that we don't have enough data.

Comment: I've added the function used to determine such values.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Your selection function is not formed correctly. I would advise a while loop instead of `if` + `recursion`.